# How to display a row in a table if a button is clicked relating to a specific record in a database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

## UPDATE: I appreciate everyone taking the time to look at my code. I figured out that the problem is not PHP, but the order of the  tag in the table being rendered.

I am fairly new to PHP.

The project I am working on calls up the unpaid invoices via a search. I have added a field where a check mark appears if the invoice is paid in full, but a button with "Add Receipt" on it if it is not paid in full.  If the button is clicked, a row should open up below that row in the table with fields for the user to input the amount, check number, etc. to pay the invoice.

I am having a problem with getting the code to just display one row relating to the unpaid invoice that was clicked on. I tried setting the button up in a form and checking isset for the form, but either nothing appears or all the rows appear for all the invoices.

Shortened HTML output is below.

I tried putting display:none and then changing that via JavaScript, but it's not working.  It doesn't change to display: block when I tried it. The code is not mine, so I can't really change too much, but any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

EDIT: Here is the JS code that I tried:

```
function new_display() {
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('addReceipt').style.display = 'none'
        }
        var x = document.getElementById('addReceipt');
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

HTML Output:

```
<td align="center"><input type="submit" onclick="openDialog()" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Add Receipt" id="hiddenRow71960" name="hiddenRow71960"></td>
```

And the row that should be hidden:

```
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><b>Amount</b><br><input style="text-align:right;" type="text" class="amtpaid" id="amtrvcd88080" name="amtrvcd88080" value=""></td><td><b>Payment Method</b><br><select name="deposittype88080" id="deposittype" 88080"="">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Cash">Cash</option>
<option value="Check">Check</option>
<option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
<option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
<option value="Wire Transfer">Wire Transfer</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="deposittype[71960]" name="deposittype[71960]" value="[71960]"></td><td><b>Payment Type</b><br><select name="paymenttype88080" id="paymenttype88080">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Payment</option>
<option value="2">Deposit</option>
<option value="3">Refund</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="paymenttype[71960]" name="paymenttype[71960]" value="[71960]"></td><td><b>Date</b><br><input type="date" name="date_entered88080" id="date_entered" value=""></td><td><b>Reference #</b><br><input size="6" id="checkno" 88080"="" name="checkno" value=""></td><td><input type="button" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Save"></td></tr>
```

I see that the surrounding div is not showing up...

Comment: is this the button that you are used to open the form ? echo '<td><input type="button" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Save"></inputbutton></td></tr></div>';

Comment: No, the button that says Add Receipt.  The Save button would then save the data entered to the database.

Comment: This is a pure JS issue, so posting PHP source is not that helpful. Try to create a  [mcve] of what you tried using just HTML and JS. (check the source view of the page, copy it, remove rows so you have two of three left, add JS)

Comment: I tried the JS, but it didn't work, so I removed it. I can try and get it back and post it. I am just wondering if it didn't work because I am echoing the HTML through PHP, or is that not correct?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this question.  I suggest you post the actual HTML and JS generated by the PHP.  And, by the way, your JS is missing from your question.

Comment: I uploaded the JS, probably around the same time that you said it was missing. I've been fiddling with it, but it's still not working.

Comment: I'm not finding `addReceipt` anywhere in the PHP code you posted. And since this is about multiple rows as far as I understand, you shouldn't use an ID anyway. Can you please do what I suggested and replace your PHP with the (shortened) HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not PHP, but the HTML that's being generated. Thank you to everyone who took the time to answer.